# How to show dropdown list items below the spinner view in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

I want to use a spinner to show dropdown list items always below the spinner view . I have tried with different implementations and searched through internet still it shows above the view.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with external libraries or that's not an option?

Comment: no. If you know any library to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Material Spinner](https://github.com/tiper/MaterialSpinner) library, you can change the `app:spinnerMode` in order to show as you want.

[image]

Comment: But if I attach the spinner at bottom the list items will show upwards know.

Comment: Yes, because there is no space left in the layout, if it shows on the bottom the user can't really choose anything. Try using a scroll view on the whole layout and check if in that case the list appears on the bottom and it scrolls automatically

Comment: I used that too. still not works. scroll view works for spinner view not working for that drop down of spinner.